# Multiple Generators

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to write a procedure for a baseball program that will use multiple generators to get strikes and balls.  My generators look like this:

```
k = (strike(x) for x in range(3) if x%1 ==0)  
w = (ball(n) for n in range(4) if x%1 == 0)
```

The procedure that I have so far looks like this:

```
def count(pitch):
    if pitch == 'strike':
        return next(k),w
    elif pitch =='ball':
        return next(w),k
```

I would like my code to return the *next* results for strike and also return the *current* for balls, **And vice versa.** Please help I'm pretty stumped.

Comment: Can you give more details about what this is _supposed_ to do? `x%1==0` is always `True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier way to do this :

```
k = [x for x in range(3)]
w = [n for n in range(4)]
i=0
j=0

def countt(pitch):
    global i
    global j
    if pitch == 'strike':

        if i==len(k)-1:
            i=0
        else:i=i+1
        return k[i],w[j]

    elif pitch =='ball':
        if j==len(w)-1:
            j=0
        else:j=j+1    
        return w[j],k[i]
```

**output:**

```
>>> countt('strike')
(1, 0)
>>> countt('strike')
(2, 0)
>>> countt('ball')
(1, 2)
>>> countt('ball')
(2, 2)
>>> countt('ball')
(3, 2)
>>> countt('strike')
(0, 3)
```

Comment: Very nice.  This is a great model for what I'm looking to do, thank you.

Comment: One last question..How would i get BOTH k and w to reset once k reaches 3 or w reaches 4?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get the "current" value of a generator without advancing the generator.  If you want to keep track of a "current" value, you need to store it yourself.  This means you'll have to refactor your code, because the `count` function will "forget" any of its values on the next call.  Here's one way to do it with a class:

```
class Count(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.k = (x for x in range(3))
        self.w = (x for x in range(4))
        self.strikes = next(self.k)
        self.balls = next(self.w)

    def count(self, pitch):
        if pitch == "strike":
            self.strikes = next(self.k)
        elif pitch == "ball":
            self.balls = next(self.w)
        return self.strikes, self.balls
```

I removed references to `strike` and `ball` functions since you don't provide info on those, but you could add them in.  Then:

```
>>> c = Count()
>>> c.count("strike")
(1, 0)
>>> c.count("strike")
(2, 0)
>>> c.count("ball")
(2, 1)
```

As @gnibbler noted in a comment, you should also think about what you're trying to do with that `x%1` business.